# How do I increase mob's knockback?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

All I want is to make when you hit a vex, it gets knocked really hard. And no, you don't need a knockback weapon. Is this possible? Please let me know.

I tried with

```
attribute @e[tag= serv1,limit= 1] minecraft:generic.attack_knockback base set 40
```

but it's the player's side.